# A Rotten Riddle

Tags: mathematics, cipher

Someone gave me a scrap of paper and told me if I could solve this, I would get a prize. The only thing on the paper was the following: `BdvryAGlELxdckgPEApujttwsfgatIzMGURzzcyejokpsyBiUgNol`

Help! What is the answer and why?

Hint1:

> Solving the cipher leads to a sentence, which in itself can be solved. Spaces are omitted.

Hint2:

> The title is a clue, but beware the rotten fish (there are several of them).

Hint3:

> This is irrational.

Hint4:

> Exponentially irrational even

Hint5:

> With this cipher, a single letter is NOT strictly mapped to another letter

Hint6:

> What mathematical constant (given by a letter) is found in the title?

Hint7:

> I'm a programmer

Hint8:

> The cipher is based on position of letter

Hint9:

> Irrationality is floored before rotting away

Hint10:

> Spaces shown for clarity (but don't count as anything in cipher)
>  `B dvr yAGlELx dckgPE Apu jt tws fga tIzMGU Rzzcyejo kpsyBi Ug Nol`

Comment: Initial text is for flavor only. Not an ongoing contest for anything, content is my own.

Comment: Not a complete solution here, but rot13 gur pncvgny yrggref fcryy ONTRY CRN VZTHE OHA. By the way, is the answer: one word, or a phrase, or a sentence, or a name, or what? Basically, what are we looking for?

Comment: Added hint with answer to that.

Comment: Rotten means Rot-10 .  "LnfbiKQvOVhnmuqZOKzetddgcpqkdSjWQEBjjmiotyuzciLsEqXyv" possibly  Enigma machine encoded.

Comment: No enigma machine used :)

Comment: @JLee He was also wrong

Comment: About Hint 2: not blowfish?

Comment: specifically herrings

Comment: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do

Comment: @SQLnoob there was a big hint in the puzzle before any hints were added. z100 picked up on a variant of it. But looking at it, yeah there's another tag I could have added, but I'm not familiar with all the tags on the site.

Comment: @Jason I guess I'll wait to see the solution when it appears. It's worth reading through that link I provided, and particularly the top-voted answer there about what makes for a well-constructed puzzle. I remain skeptical that this puzzle would have been solvable without the 7+ hints you've provided so far, but I could certainly be wrong about that.

Comment: About Hint #5: "a single letter is NOT strictly mapped to another letter" Does that mean that a single letter does not always map to the same letter, or that one letter may map to nothing or even to more than one letter? Or does it mean something else entirely?

Comment: It will always map to one letter at a time, but not necessarily the same letter each time.

Comment: @SQLnoob Yeah, I do think I could have incorporated some of the hints into the puzzle as well. My next puzzle should be much easier than this one.

Comment: Some hints were published when it was already clear (1,5,8), 7 is almost unusable, 2 an 6  ok. Shift (rot) cipher using key related to $e$ ... but no usable result yet. Need new hint.

Comment: I'm trying to think of another hint that won't just give away the answer, but yes you are really close. Rot13: Cebtenzzref trarenyyl qba'g fgneg pbhag ng 1.

Comment: No more hints please, let us suffer some more ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process:

> For each letter in the ciphertext, raise $e$ to the power of its position in the string (starting with 0). Take the floor of the result and ROT the letter that many positions.

The resulting text (with spaces added) is:

> a box without hinges key or lid yet golden treasure inside is hid

And so the answer is:

> **An egg.**

Comment: What? [He stabs him]

Comment: @Auribouros lol i figured this one might be something like this

Comment: V tenivgngrq gb r jura uvag #3 jnf cbfgrq, ohg ng gur gvzr V qvqa'g qernz bs nqqvat va nyy gubfr bgure fgrcf.

Comment: Yep, that is it, You get a rotten egg (or not, the prize stinks)! Congrats!